# How can I replace an img src with a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and I'd like to replace the URL part with a variable. How can I do this?

```
$('#grid_1').find('img').not('img[src="***https://zukan.pokemon.co.jp/zukan-api/up/images/index/cdce516974ae6a74e1b8b855644c5ce5.png***"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var src = "https://zukan.pokemon.co.jp/zukan-api/up/images/index/cdce516974ae6a74e1b8b855644c5ce5.png"

$('#grid_1').find('img').not('img[src="'+src+'"]').hide();
```

But I suggest using a class to hide and it will be more clear.

Comment: That's what I wanted! It completely works! Thank you, Aruna!

Comment: It's really wonderful to hear that :) . And accept it if correct ;)